# Reduce duplicated code, trying to assign a function to a variable - doesnt work

Tags: javascript, function, dry

To reduce duplicated code I tried to create an if statement to assign a variable a function or another but this didn't work!?

What I tried doing was

```
const graphCall = (params['sfid'] === 'potential_engagements') ?  this.engagementService.potentialsGraph() : this.engagementService.graph()
```

that syntax itself doesn't throw an error but then when I try to use

```
graphCall.then(animate =>
```

... it doesn't work!
Am I missing something, can I not assign functions this away, is there another way similar or a different way to check and remove the duplicated code?

My code:

```
if (params['sfid'] === 'potential_engagements') {
    this.engagementService.potentialEngagements = true;
    this.engagementService
      .potentialsGraph()
      .then(animate => {
        this.graph = new EngagementGraph(d3.select('.Engagement-GraphSVG'));
        this.track();
        this.engagementService.isGraph = true;
        this.engagementService
          .getAllProducts()
          .then(() => this.downloading = false)
          .catch(err => this.pdfError = true)
        this.findForumContact();
        this.updateDateLabel();
        this.addMemberPicture();
        this.setup(animate);
      })
      .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
} else {
    this.engagementService
      .graph(params['sfid'])
      .then(animate => {
        this.graph = new EngagementGraph(d3.select('.Engagement-GraphSVG'));
        this.track();
        this.engagementService.isGraph = true;
        this.engagementService
          .getAllProducts()
          .then(() => this.downloading = false)
          .catch(err => this.pdfError = true)
        this.findForumContact();
        this.updateDateLabel();
        this.addMemberPicture();
        this.setup(animate);
      })
      .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
}
```

Thanks if you can help!

Comment: Find where your error occur first

Comment: I think your problem is the promise has already resolved by the time you call .then, so you should try assigning the var to `engagementService.potentialsGraph` without the brackets `()`. That way the promise will invoke when you call it.

Comment: Just to clarify: `graphCall = (params['sfid'] === 'potential_engagements') ? this.engagementService.potentialsGraph : this.engagementService.graph`

Comment: Hi @enf0rcer, problem is I need to pass a parameter value to the .graph function

Comment: Hi adiga, how would that affect the .potentialsGrap h function? it's checking for a parameter 'params' value

Comment: @Sparlarva that's no problem, JavaScript has a solution for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `potential_engagements` block has two things that the other block doesn't:

```
this.engagementService.potentialEngagements = true; <------
this.engagementService
  .potentialsGraph() <------
  .then(animate => {
```

The other block has only one thing the other block doesn't:

```
this.engagementService
  .graph(params['sfid']) <------
  .then(animate => {
```

The `.then(animate` and everything following it is the same, so I'd suggest abstracting all of that into a function, perhaps called `handleGraphProm`:

```
const handleGraphProm = prom => prom.then(animate => {
  this.graph = new EngagementGraph(d3.select('.Engagement-GraphSVG'));
  this.track();
  this.engagementService.isGraph = true;
  this.engagementService
    .getAllProducts()
    .then(() => this.downloading = false)
    .catch(err => this.pdfError = true)
  this.findForumContact();
  this.updateDateLabel();
  this.addMemberPicture();
  this.setup(animate);
})
.catch(error => this.handleError(error));
```

And call it with:

```
if (params['sfid'] === 'potential_engagements') {
  this.engagementService.potentialEngagements = true;
  handleGraphProm(this.engagementService.potentialsGraph());
} else {
  handleGraphProm(this.engagementService..graph(params['sfid']));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is probably because you have an additional `this.engagementService.potentialEngagements = true` which is not being assigned in the ternary operation. Put the `thenable` returned by `potentialsGraph` and `graph` to variable. And then call `then` on it:

```
let graphCall;

if (params['sfid'] === 'potential_engagements') {
  this.engagementService.potentialEngagements = true;
  graphCall = this.engagementService.potentialsGraph()
} else {
  graphCall = this.engagementService.graph(params['sfid'])
}

graphCall.then(animate => {
    this.graph = new EngagementGraph(d3.select('.Engagement-GraphSVG'));
    this.track();
    this.engagementService.isGraph = true;
    this.engagementService
      .getAllProducts()
      .then(() => this.downloading = false)
      .catch(err => this.pdfError = true)
    this.findForumContact();
    this.updateDateLabel();
    this.addMemberPicture();
    this.setup(animate);
  })
  .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
```